# Do Navagraha follow the law of Karma

Tags: asuras, navagraha, devatas

Sun(deva himself, he is also regarded as Vishnu himself) , Jupiter(guru of Deva), How can they do bad to people, Also do Navagraha follow the "Law of Karma", Is it the punishments that Graha gives us for own past deeds? I also don't understand Why are Rahu and Ketu worshipped if they were from the Asura Swarbhanu?

This answers to this question say that worshipping them reduces their malefic effects, But why worship them in the first? - [Why worship, respect and do pradikshna for Rahu and Ketu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29101/why-worship-respect-and-do-pradikshna-for-rahu-and-ketu)

Comment: For humans Navagrahas give rewards/punishments. For Grahas themselves there must exist another system.

Comment: Rahu and Ketu when joined is an Asura. When they are separate they are deities and worship worthy.