# Is Shani graha same as Shani deva?

Tags: astrology, navagraha

Shani  graha is one of the graha in Vedic astrology.

Shani  deva is one of the god/devtha in Hinduism.

Are they both same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can Wind, Sun and Fire be living beings?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27837/how-can-wind-sun-and-fire-be-living-beings)

Comment: Yeah, almost.... But wants to know about Seni

Comment: @YDS. ......................

Comment: It's applicable for all grahas.. @hanugm

Answer (score 5):

They are the same. We can show that by using the [Dasaratha Krita Shani Stotram](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Sanaischarashtakam). Here Shani is mentioned both as a Deva (god) as well as a Graha who have influence in the astrological charts of human beings.
Quoting few verses from the Stotra will make things clear:

> Desascha durgani vanani yathra,
>  Senanivesaa pura pattanani,
> Peedynthi sarve vishama sthithena,
>  Thasmai nama Ravinandanaya., 4
>
> **Salutations to the son of Sun god, Who creates problems, if in bad position,** Even to country, to deep forests, to forts, Even to tents
> of army and to the cities.
>
> Thilair yavair masha gudanna dhanai,
>  Lohena neelambara dhanatho
> va,
>  Preenathi manthrair nija vasare cha,
>  Thasmai nama
> Ravinandanaya., 5
>
> Salutations to the son of Sun god, Who gets pleased if gingelly,
> Barley, jaggery rice, iron and, Blue cloths are given in charity on
> Saturdays, Or if he is worshipped on Saturdays.

"Salutations to the son of Sun God" -- this shows that Shani is a God and at the same time it is also said of him " Who creates problems, if in bad position" --- which is referring to the fact that Shani is a Graha who creates problems if badly placed in the horoscope of an individual.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

As per Astrology, its Shani Grah. 
Since Shani is considered as critical element in Astrology, Its being worshipped so being called as Shani dev also. 
In general also we believe most natural element as God.

Comment: You should cite some reliable sources while answering questions